# Add EditText to ExpandableListView in Android

Tags: android

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ExpandableListView expandableListView;
ExpandableListAdapter expandableListAdapter;
List<String> expandableListTitle;
HashMap<String, List<String>> expandableListDetail;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    try {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        expandableListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expandableListView);
        //expandableListDetail = ExpandableListDataPump.getData();
        //expandableListTitle = new ArrayList<String>(expandableListDetail.keySet());
        expandableListTitle = new ArrayList<>();
        expandableListDetail = new HashMap<>();
        expandableListAdapter = new CustomExpandableListAdapter(this, expandableListTitle, expandableListDetail);
        expandableListView.setAdapter(expandableListAdapter);
        expandableListTitle.add("List title");
        expandableListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener() {

            @Override
            public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        expandableListTitle.get(groupPosition) + " List Expanded.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        expandableListView.setOnGroupCollapseListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupCollapseListener() {

            @Override
            public void onGroupCollapse(int groupPosition) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        expandableListTitle.get(groupPosition) + " List Collapsed.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });

        expandableListView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                        int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
                try {
                    Toast.makeText(
                            getApplicationContext(),
                            expandableListTitle.get(groupPosition)
                                    + " -> "
                                    + expandableListDetail.get(
                                    expandableListTitle.get(groupPosition)).get(
                                    childPosition), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                    ).show();

                }catch (Exception e){
                    Log.e("Child","Excep due to"+e.toString());
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("/Test","/Excp due to"+e.toString());
    }
}
}



import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CustomExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

private Context context;
private List<String> expandableListTitle;
private HashMap<String, List<String>> expandableListDetail;
final EditText[] etIndividualLetterValues = new EditText[26];
public CustomExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> expandableListTitle,
                                   HashMap<String, List<String>> expandableListDetail) {
    try {
        this.context = context;
        this.expandableListTitle = expandableListTitle;
        this.expandableListDetail = expandableListDetail;
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("/Test","/Excp due to"+e.toString());
    }
}
public CustomExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> expandableListTitle){
    try{
        this.context=context;
        this.expandableListTitle=expandableListTitle;
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("/test","/Exception due to"+e.toString());
    }

}
@Override
public Object getChild(int listPosition, int expandedListPosition) {
    return this.expandableListDetail.get(this.expandableListTitle.get(listPosition))
            .get(expandedListPosition);
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int listPosition, int expandedListPosition) {
    return expandedListPosition;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int listPosition, final int expandedListPosition,
                         boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    try {
        final String expandedListText = (String) getChild(listPosition, expandedListPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        }
        EditText expandedListEditText = (EditText) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.expandedListItem);
        expandedListEditText.setText(expandedListText);
        return convertView;
    }catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("/Test","/Excp due to"+e.toString());
        return null;
    }
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int listPosition) {
    return this.expandableListDetail.get(this.expandableListTitle.get(listPosition))
            .size();
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int listPosition) {
    return this.expandableListTitle.get(listPosition);
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return this.expandableListTitle.size();
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int listPosition) {
    return listPosition;
}


@Override
public View getGroupView(int listPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                         View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    try {
        String listTitle = (String) getGroup(listPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.
                    getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
        }
        TextView listTitleTextView = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.listTitle);
        listTitleTextView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        listTitleTextView.setText(listTitle);
        return convertView;
    }catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("/Test","/Excp due to"+e.toString());
        return null;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int listPosition, int expandedListPosition) {
    return true;
}
}
```

list_group.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/listTitle"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:text="textview"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

list_item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/expandedListItem"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredChildPaddingLeft"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:hint="Test"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I have posted all my code. When I click on list title, It's not expanding the list it shows "Unfortunately Stopped". This code sets the title to Expandablelistview. But it does not set the EditText to the Expandablelistview. Why? Is there any changed needed in setOnChildClickListener method?

How to add `EditText`. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: post your stacktrace as well

Comment: where is ur edittext?

Comment: I have updated my code. @keshav

Comment: Sir, Once check my code and tell me, why Edittext is not set to Expandablelistview and why the list is not expanding? @keshav

Comment: can u share ur list_group and list_item too?

Comment: I have shared list_group and list_item in my code. check sir @keshav

Comment: post the exception stacktrace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is when u are initializing the **list** and **hashmap**. The way u have written ur adapter it should be initialized like following.

```
expandableListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expandableListView);
        //expandableListDetail = ExpandableListDataPump.getData();
        //expandableListTitle = new ArrayList<String>(expandableListDetail.keySet());


        expandableListTitle = new ArrayList<>();
        expandableListTitle.add("Address");
        expandableListTitle.add("Address");
//        expandableListTitle.add("Address");
        expandableListTitle1 = new ArrayList<>();
        expandableListTitle1.add("Enter State here");
        expandableListTitle1.add("Enter Country here");

        expandableListDetail = new HashMap<>();
    expandableListDetail.put(expandableListTitle.get(0),expandableListTitle1);

        expandableListAdapter = new CustomExpandableListAdapter(this, expandableListTitle, expandableListDetail);
        expandableListView.setAdapter(expandableListAdapter);
```

[image: The result of above]

```
public class CustomExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private List<String> expandableListTitle;
    private HashMap<String, List<String>> expandableListDetail;
    final EditText[] etIndividualLetterValues = new EditText[26];

    public CustomExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> expandableListTitle,
                                       HashMap<String, List<String>> expandableListDetail) {
        try {
            this.context = context;
            this.expandableListTitle = expandableListTitle;
            this.expandableListDetail = expandableListDetail;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("/Test", "/Excp due to" + e.toString());
        }
    }

    public CustomExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> expandableListTitle) {
        try {
            this.context = context;
            this.expandableListTitle = expandableListTitle;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("/test", "/Exception due to" + e.toString());
        }

    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int listPosition, int expandedListPosition) {
        return this.expandableListDetail.get(this.expandableListTitle.get(listPosition))
                .get(expandedListPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int listPosition, int expandedListPosition) {
        return expandedListPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int listPosition, final int expandedListPosition,
                             boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        try {
            final String expandedListText = (String) getChild(listPosition, expandedListPosition);
            if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
            }
            EditText expandedListEditText = (EditText) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.expandedListItem);
            //expandedListEditText.setText(expandedListText);


expandedListEditText.setHint(expandedListText);
            return convertView;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("/Test", "/Excp due to" + e.toString());
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int listPosition) {
        return this.expandableListDetail.get(this.expandableListTitle.get(listPosition))
                .size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int listPosition) {
        return this.expandableListTitle.get(listPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return this.expandableListTitle.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int listPosition) {
        return listPosition;
    }


    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int listPosition, boolean isExpanded,View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        try {
            String listTitle = (String) getGroup(listPosition);
            if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.
                        getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
            }
            TextView listTitleTextView = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.listTitle);
            listTitleTextView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
            listTitleTextView.setText(listTitle);
            return convertView;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("/Test", "/Excp due to" + e.toString());
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int listPosition, int expandedListPosition) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: can u please include your code in my adapter, and post the code please?@keshav

Comment: I m using the exact code of ur adapter. btw I will add it here.

Comment: Sir, i am getting the Edittexts as shown in your screenshot. But when I am entering text and move to next field my entered data has gone and again set to Listtitle1.why? For example. If i enter `india` in 1st text field. when I click on 2nd edittext to enter data, the first textfield data has gone and set to `list title1`.

Comment: remove/comment  expandedListEditText.setText(expandedListText); line as I did in updated answer.

Comment: can you please tell me what this line did in the code?expandableListDetail.put(expandableListTitle.get(0),expandableListTitle);

Comment: That is called everytime the view is recreated and sets the value of edittext with the list value..

Comment: My problem is I don't want to set the list value to the edittext. please consider my requirement. I want List title as "Address" and first edit text has hint "Enter State here" and second edittext has hint "Enter Country here". please can you do it for me sir? @keshav

Comment: Then use             expandedListEditText.setHint("Hint text");

Comment: From your code I wriiten code for my requirement is:expandableListTitle.add("Address"); \\setting the title as address expandableListDetail.put(expandableListTitle.get(0),expandableListTitle);// for first edittext
    expandableListDetail.put(expandableListTitle.get(1),expandableListTitle);//for second edittext. Here the problem was there is only one listview title then how can I get the Second edittext. In this case I am not getting anything. so, what is the solution?

Comment: You have given me almost the solution sir. please tell me this last thing @keshav

Comment: It's working but what these 2 lines did? expandableListTitle1.add("Enter state here");
            expandableListTitle1.add("Enter Country here"); these lines not added to Edittext right?@keshav